# mysql query, select rows distict and other rows is not distict

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to query the table with the result of name rows is distinct and the email rows are not distinct

have this in my databasse looks like

```
Name    Email
john    emai1@mywebsite.com
john    emai1@mywebsite.com
john    emai1@mywebsite.com
pedro   emai12@mywebsite.com
pedro   emai12@mywebsite.com
pedro   emai12@mywebsite.com
```

and i want this query result

```
Name    Email
john    emai1@mywebsite.com
        emai1@mywebsite.com
        emai1@mywebsite.com
```

---

```
pedro   emai12@mywebsite.com
        emai12@mywebsite.com
        emai12@mywebsite.com
```

PLease i need your help. and thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Post your query/ code your using now!

Comment: Do you want the email three times (email12@mywebsite.com) for example - or do you want it only shown once as well?

Comment: your question is about a query but the code you posted is html code. please revise your question so we can help you

Comment: i email show three time or more... but the name is only once

Answer (score 0):

your question is about a query but the code you posted is html code. please revise your question so we can help you

But you would want to do something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT first_name, last_name, email
FROM table
```

Comment: but i need name will show only once or unique, and the email is show many times.......